# Ввод с клавиатуры java

Tags: java

Привет! Решаю задачки в java через intelijidea. Нужно внести с клавиатуры два числа, могу ли я сам как-то их ввести, чтобы проверить вывод? Дело в том, что при решении задачи вывод не показывается, т.к. нет внесенных с клавиатуры данных, только результат компиляции. Спасибо.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String numa = reader.readLine();
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numa);
    String numb = reader.readLine();
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numb);

    for (int i = 1; i <= num1; num1++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= num2; num2++)
        {
            System.out.print(8);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ну а чего нет-то? Для отладки временно присвойте какие-то значения своим переменным сами вручника и все, а те поля временно закоментируйте

Comment: В IDEA есть консоль. Что не так?

Comment: @LEQADA - не умею пользоваться консолью.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Intellij IDEA есть консоль. Туда можно и писать и видеть вывод программы. Вот пример кода с картинкой из IDE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter some number: ");
        int input = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your input is: " + input);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Закомментируйте данные два предложения

```
// String numa = reader.readLine();
// String numb = reader.readLine();
```

и вместо них запишите те значения, которые хотите протестировать. Например

```
String numa = "10";
String numb = "20";
```

Comment: Еще num1 и num2 забыли)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Зачем? Они получаются из строк.

Comment: Да, я что-то невнимательной посмотел

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num1; num1++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= num2; num2++)
        {
            System.out.print(8);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

---

у вас ошибка при использовании for , т.к. получается бесконечный цикл , где увеличивается числа num1 и num2