# Класс для чтения стандартного потока ввода из консоли

Tags: java, io, ввод

Какой класс использовать для получение данных введенных через консоль.
Для вывода я знаю `System.out.print` а для ввода что?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ввод с клавиатуры java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466202/%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-java)

Comment: Не нужно выность в заголовок вопроса весь текст вопроса целиком.

Answer (score 8):

**"Введите что-то и нажмите Enter":**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // нужно только 1 раз
String line = in.nextLine();
```

Или:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // нужно только 1 раз
String line = br.readLine();
```